# Check if a value is in one of two columns with doctrine query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I'm attempting build a query that will check an entity `Project` and check two columns either `project_owner` or `project_contributor` where project contributor is a Many to One relation.

The query I attempted to make was this (in the project entity repository):

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
     ->where('p.project_owner = :val')
     ->orWhere(':val in p.project_contributors')
     ->setParameter('val', $value)
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult()
;
```

The error I received was the following:

`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 75: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS, got 'p'`

Clearly this is the wrong approach. What is the right one? I'm trying to understand the query builder better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an inner join of the many to one relation, and then filter those.

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
   ->innerJoin('p.project_contributors', 'pc')
   ->where('p.project_owner = :val')
   ->orWhere('pc.name = :val')
   ->setParameter('val', $value)
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: Why do you have `pc.name`? That's not a column.

Comment: The correct field would be, in my case, `pc.id`

Comment: Ok. There was no way for me to know :)

Comment: Sorry I was wondering what the use for that column was originally until I realized that's where the merge was happening. Thanks :)